# SubscribeOn uses only 1 thread from the pool

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

There are many questions on subscribeOn and in theory it is simple: it makes the subscriber process run with specific Scheduler. However when I run this:

```
    @Test
void fluxWithSubscribeOnTest() {
    final Scheduler s = Schedulers.newParallel("parallel", 10);
    final Publisher<Integer> integerFlux =
            Flux
                    .range(1, 1000)
                    .doOnNext(integer -> log.info("executed"))
                    .subscribeOn(s);
    StepVerifier.create(integerFlux)
            .expectNextCount(1000)
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

I see all 1000 logs are written in the same parallel-1 thread

```
18:39:47.612 [parallel-1] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
18:39:47.613 [parallel-1] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
18:39:47.613 [parallel-1] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
18:39:47.613 [parallel-1] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
18:39:47.613 [parallel-1] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
18:39:47.613 [parallel-1] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
18:39:47.613 [parallel-1] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
18:39:47.613 [parallel-1] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
```

I'd expect the above code to log (so perform onNext) in multiple threads from the pool provided with the subscribeOn. ParallelFlux work that way and, as expected, it logs in different threads:

```
    @Test
void parallelFluxTest() {
    final Scheduler s = Schedulers.newParallel("parallel", 10);
    final Publisher<Integer> integerFlux =
            Flux
                    .range(1, 1000)
                    .parallel(10)
                    .runOn(s)
                    .doOnNext(integer -> log.info("executed"));
    StepVerifier.create(integerFlux)
            .expectNextCount(1000)
            .verifyComplete();
}

18:43:42.377 [parallel-1] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
18:43:42.377 [parallel-2] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
18:43:42.377 [parallel-3] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
18:43:42.377 [parallel-4] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
18:43:42.378 [parallel-5] INFO com.performance.TestClass - executed
```

Can someone explain why the subscribeOn example logs with only one thread while the pool size is 10?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confused because of the word "parallel" when you use `Scheduler.parallel()` or `Scheduler.newParallel()`

**"parallel" in this case does not mean it magically makes your processing parallel by default.**

It means that scheduler has fixed thread pool that is meant to perform some CPU-bound operations and **is suited for parallel work.**

It is recommended to use this scheduler for performing CPU-bound operations.

About `Flux.range()` : this method is meant to emit a sequence of count incrementing integers, starting from start. It is a sequential operation in your first case, it emits the numbers on a thread from which you subscribed to your flux. There is no any parallel work unless you use `parallel()` with `runOn()`

Answer (score 1):

the behaviour you are seeing is pointed out in the [reactor documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-parallelizing-parralelflux) which states:

> To obtain a ParallelFlux, you can use the parallel() operator on any Flux. By itself, this method does not parallelize the work. Rather, it divides the workload into “rails” (by default, as many rails as there are CPU cores).
>
> In order to tell the resulting ParallelFlux where to run each rail (and, by extension, to run rails in parallel) you have to use runOn(Scheduler). Note that there is a recommended dedicated Scheduler for parallel work: Schedulers.parallel().

So you need `rails` to be able to split up work. And to assign split up work on different cores you need a `parallel scheduler`.

Which means your first example has threads on multiple cores because of the scheduler. But the `Flux` itself has not the ability to split up the work and assign it to different cores.

So basically your first example is allocating threads on multiple cores that aren't used.

Remember, I/O work as logging, making requests, reading/writing files, usually don't benefit from parallel work. You are basically putting out work on multiple cores that still have to wait for other things like file handles getting freed, other services responding etc. etc.

So you are basically allocating a lot of resources for very little gain.

I/O work is more orchestration than raw computing power, and parallel work mostly shines if you need to do heavy cpu bound calculations.

So not logging.